# Reset Fields doesn't contain values specified in Standard Values of a template

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, field

I am trying to get the Reset Fields option in Sitecore to work for a specific item template. In this template I specify different types of fields including Droplink fields. For all fields that I have entered standard values for the correct values are suggested in the Reset Fields option (Under the Version Ribbon - Fields - Reset), except for all of my droplink field values. I have - in the standard values item of the template - selected the standard values for the droplink. On creation of an item of this template the correct Droplink values are selected, but when using the Reset Fields option I am not seeing the correct standard value suggested.
What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reseting the field, the item should display "[standard value]" in light grey text beside the field. If it is not, the field is not being reset and that is the problem.

If this *is* being displayed, then I would guess that you have more than one __standard Values in effect. Standard values cascade through inheritance. So:

basetemplate1 (stdVals1) -> maintemplate1 (stdVals2) -> item1

After reseting the field on "item1" you are expecting the value of "stdVals1" to appear, but because "stdVals2" has been actively set to nothing, you are seeing that value.

To resolve this, you would need to reset the field for item1 *and* stdVals2, then you should see the value from stdVals1 appear in item1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I will have a look and try it when I have the possibility.